# Python Selenium ActionChains - drag_and_drop method isn't working properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to drag and drop an element using ActionChains. But can't get it to work.

Environment:

- Python 3.x
- Selenium 3.14.x
- Driver: Chrome
- PC: Mac OS X 10.14.15
- Url: https://demoqa.com/sortable/

So there are two drag and drop methods:

drag_and_drop

drag_and_drop_by_offset

When I try with offset it works but when I use regular drag_and_drop it doesn't.

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://demoqa.com/")

sortable_button = driver.find_element(
    By.CSS_SELECTOR, "aside.widget:nth-of-type(1) li:nth-of-type(1)")
sortable_button.click()
items = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#sortable li")
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.drag_and_drop_by_offset(items[0], 0, 200).perform()
# actions.drag_and_drop(items[0], items[4]).perform()
time.sleep(5)
driver.close()
```

Comment: On HTML5 drag_and_drop is not working

Comment: I see. Is it something that Selenium has to look into?

Comment: @ yep they need to update code for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that drag_and_drop method doesn't work with HTML5

Here's a reference that provides a workaround and a confirmation by selenium dev that indeed it doesn't work on HTML5

https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/3604